# C: How do I structure a line_buffer to not overwrite?

Tags: c, buffer

The following code seems to overwrite a so that it only contains a bunch of lines that are the same as the last line of the input file. How do I structure the while loop so it stores each buffer line in a separate instance of the array?

```
void readfile(const char *filename) {
FILE *f;
f = fopen(filename, "r");
char *a[500];
char *array[50];
char line_buffer[BUFSIZ];
char line=0;
//struct cal_event one[200];

while (fgets(line_buffer, sizeof(line_buffer), f)) {
    ++line;
    a[line] = (char*) &line_buffer;
    //printf("%s ", a[line]);
}
int l;
for(l=1; l<30; l++) {
    printf("%s ", a[l]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to allocate a new buffer for each line and assign the address to `a[line]`.

Assigning the pointer should probably look like:

```
a[line++] = ...
```

So that the first assignment is the first element at offset 0, instead of the second element at offset 1 as you have it now.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to allocate space for each line. Leaving out error checking and such, the usual is something like:

```
char buffer[max_line_len];
char *lines[max_lines];
size_t line=0;

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), f)) {
    lines[line] = malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
    strcpy(lines[line], buffer);
    ++line;
}
```

Comment: I'm not supposed to use malloc.

Comment: @KimberleeGraham-Knight: In that case you can pre-allocate `lines` (or whatever name you prefer) as something like `char lines[max_lines][max_length];` and just read each line directly into the correct spot in it. Wasteful enough that it's rarely used, but works fine other than that.